# Python Requests OS Error 104 Connection Broken Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, azure-databricks, chunked-encoding

Hi I am trying to a hit an API using requests module of python. The Api has to be hit 20000 times as the number of pages are around 20000. In every hit the data comes around 10 mb. By the end of the process it creates a json file of around 100gb. Here is the code I have written

```
with open('file.json','wb',buffering=100*1048567) as f:
  while(next_page_cursor != ""):
    with request.get(url,headers=headers) as response:
      json_response = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8')) 
      """
      json response looks something like this 
      {
        content:[{},{},{}........50 dictionaries]
        next_page_cursor : "abcd"
      }
      """
      next_page_cursor = json_response['next_page_cursor']

      for data in json_response['content']:
        f.write((json.dumps(data) + "\n").encode())
```

But after running successfully for few pages the code fails giving the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<command-1206920060120926>", line 65, in <module>
    with requests.get(data_url, headers = headers) as response:
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 686, in send
    r.content
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 828, in content
    self._content = b''.join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or b''
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 753, in generate
    raise ChunkedEncodingError(e)
requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ('Connection broken: OSError("(104, \'ECONNRESET\')")', OSError("(104, 'ECONNRESET')"))
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `response.iter_content`

https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.iter_content

Comment: But that will convert the response in binary format. So How would I capture the next page cursor from a binary response

Comment: yeah sorry, may be I was too quick to answer. your situation looks different. your json reponse tells you if you have to do next request or not. so may be does not fit for your situation right away

Comment: the other thing I could think of is to try a timeout value in request.get